# Is there induced current if a horizontal rod move sideways in a vertically uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: Figure 1][image: Figure]
In figure 1, there is a metal rod connected with a wire in a uniform magnetic field. If it is moved sideways and a part of its body is leaving the field, what will happen?

1. Is there induced e.m.f.?
2. Is there induced current?
3. What is the direction of the induced current? (if any)

My thinking:

- If we observe figure 1 from bird's eye view, we will have figure 2.
- From figure 2, I see that the rod is cutting through the field with
  its short edges.
- By Faraday's law, there will be an induced e.m.f.
- By Fleming's right-hand rule, there will be an electric current going
  upwards (for figure 2).
- However, wires are at left and right, not on the upper nor lower side. Positions of the wires does not match with the direction of the current.
- I guess the lower body of the rod will be negatively charged as electrons will be accumulated there and there is NO induced current in the rod?

Comment: you missed that it is leaving the magnetic field, that is the important part.

Answer (score 1):

> By Faraday's law, there will be an induced e.m.f.

(Deep, friendly voiced) Hm, is that so?

Faraday's law of induction states:

> Take any closed loop of conductor, and consider the area that is enclosed by that loop. If you take the magnetic field that goes through area, and find the derivative of that integral, that's the negated EMF.

As far as I interpret your pictures, the magnetic flux (the magnetic field integrated over that area) simply doesn't change, because your loop moves within a homogenous field.

So, no change in integral over time, and thus, no EMF.

Comment: It is written in my textbook that Faraday's law states that "the magnitude of the induced e.m.f. is directly proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic field passing through a coil, or the rate at which the conductor cuts through the magnetic field lines". For this case, I guess it is the conductor cutting through the field. Also, the loop is actually moving out of the field. It was my fault for not drawing it properly in the figure.

Comment: yes, that's a slightly less precise description, because you need to define what exactly you observe the change of that gives you a single-valued function which you can differentiate to get the EMF (which is the integral I mention). What your textbook and I say is identical! But that's the point: your conductor cuts through a homogeneous field. The amount of field passing through the coil: it doesn't change!